# MySQL find out percentage of column

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table 'training record' which keeps track of users training status (training_status_id). This can be recorded as:

1 - not trained
2 - training not complete
3 - fully trained

I would like to get the percentage of "fully trained" staff. Is this achievable through a mysql query?

i.e 80% of staff are fully trained

Comment: you can count the total of fully trained and then do your percentage as usual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining SUM & CASE is one way to go here:

```
select sum(case when training_status_id=3 then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as percentage
from training_record;
```